# Mobile Safari Zoom lens control

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-graphics

In response to a long press Mobile Safari shows a zoom lens/eyeglass. Anyone knows anything about implementing this behavior in some other UIView based app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Any correctly configured `UITextView`, `UITextField` etc. shows this exact behaviour. (To be more exact, anything that is 'selectable') To implement this behaviour, you have to write your own methods. Apple does not provide anything like this.

Comment: Thanks this is a custom UIView that has custom drawing. Anyone could suggest any techniques to implement this?